# Refactoring Java code

Tags: java

Can someone explain me how to refactor the below code. Basically i have a timer functionality which i am using repeatedly. So i want to put that timer into a generic function.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class App {
    private volatile boolean a = false;
    private volatile boolean b = false;
    private volatile boolean c = false;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App app = new App();
        app.m1();
    }

    private void m1() {
        // m2() should not take more than specified time in timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(a){
                    System.out.println("m1 Do nothing");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("m1 Timeout exception");
                }
            }
        }, 2*60*1000);
        a=m2();
        System.out.println("Blah");
    }
    private boolean m2() {
        // Killing some time with sleep
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //m3() should not take more than specified time in timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(b){
                    System.out.println("m2 Do nothing");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("m2 Timeout exception");
                }               
            }
        }, 1*60*1000);
        b = m3();
        System.out.println("Blah Blah");
        return true;
    }
    private boolean m3() {
        //m4() should not take more than specified time in timer
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if(c){
                    System.out.println("m3 Do nothing");
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println("m3 Timeout exception");
                }           
            }
        }, 20000);
        c=m4();
        System.out.println("Blah Blah Blah");
        return true;
    }
    private boolean m4() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help. I am not looking for code help. Want to know your thoughts on minimizing the code.

Comment: This question belongs in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is the difference between these timers?

Comment: @Jens I think the point of the question is that there isn't much difference.

Comment: @immibis there must be a difference. If not you do not need 3 timers.

Comment: @Jens they check different variables, and print different messages.

Comment: This question belongs on another site: code.stackexchange.com

Comment: First of all, I am sorry for late reply.Thank you All for your quick response. The timer functionality is to make sure the method followed by it is not taking more than the specified time. If it takes more time, I have to throw TimeOutException. How i am checking this is, using the volatile variables.And i posted the question http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/61837/refactoring-java-code